Migrating to SwiftUI, View Not Displaying Full Screen Despite Using .ignoresSafeArea
I'm working on a project that is transitioning from UIKit to SwiftUI, and I'm encountering an issue where my views do not display in full screen, even though I've used .ignoresSafeArea(.all).
Here’s a simplified version of my code:
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            HotelView()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Hotels", systemImage: "bed.double.fill")
                }
            SettingsView()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Settings", systemImage: "gear")
                }
        }
        .accentColor(.blue)
        .ignoresSafeArea(.all)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

import SwiftUI

enum Page {
    case launch
    case home
    case settings 
}

class ViewRouter: ObservableObject {
    @Published var currentPage: Page = .launch
}


import SwiftUI

@main
struct NameApp: App {
    @StateObject var viewRouter = ViewRouter()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            switch viewRouter.currentPage {
            case .launch:
                LaunchScreen()
                    .environmentObject(viewRouter)
                    .ignoresSafeArea(.all)
            case .home:
                ContentView()
                    .environmentObject(viewRouter)
                    .ignoresSafeArea(.all)
            case .settings:
                SettingsView()
                    .environmentObject(viewRouter)
                    .ignoresSafeArea(.all)
            }
        }
    }
}


Despite using .ignoresSafeArea, the view appears cropped or doesn’t fill the entire screen. I'm also working with some UIKit controllers (like UIViewController for certain views) but haven't seen any obvious conflicts.
Has anyone encountered a similar issue or knows of any potential causes?
Thanks in advance!

Please show a [mcve] - some code that I can directly paste into a new project and reproduce the issue.

Make sure you are pinning the UIViewControllers to the SwiftUI parent with constraints. If you don’t then SwiftUI doesn’t have control of the size.

Try adding .ignoresSafeArea() to the child views of the TabView, or even inside these views. It is not needed on the TabView itself.
The updated example below demonstrates it working. The modifier .ignoresSafeArea() is commented out for the yellow view:
TabView {
    Color.yellow
        // .ignoresSafeArea()
        .overlay { Text("HotelView") }
        .tabItem {
            Label("Hotels", systemImage: "bed.double.fill")
        }
    Color.green
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        .overlay { Text("SettingsView") }
        .tabItem {
            Label("Settings", systemImage: "gear")
        }
}
.accentColor(.blue)



Thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately, applying .ignoresSafeArea() to the child views (like HotelView and SettingsView) didn’t resolve the issue. The views are still not displaying in full screen and remain cropped. Is there another approach I could try to ensure full-screen views in a TabView?

https://ibb.co/c6cyZ75
That´s what i get in then view from beginning.

@user102623 OK, so there is some view in there with a gradient background. Try setting .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity) on the parent container and .ignoresSafeArea() on the gradient (which is perhaps a background layer). Also, make sure you are not setting a frame with a fixed width or height, not even if it is (supposed to be) the size of the screen. If you could post the actual code that produces that result then it would make it much easier to help you work out the cause of the problem.

Thanks for the suggestion! I tried applying .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity) to the parent container and used .ignoresSafeArea() on the gradient background, but unfortunately, the issue still persists. I made sure to remove any fixed width or height, but the black bars at the top and bottom of the screen are still there. Do you think there's anything else I could try?

@user102623 If you can please update the post to include a minimal reproducible example then it may be possible to help you more. This should be complete and should run in isolation. At the moment, all I can do is guess at the cause, without very much luck so far.
